# Effect of matrix multiplication on spectral decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Assume that we have a symmetric matrix $A$ and a positive definite matrix $B$. How is the spectral decomposition of $B^{\frac{1}{2}} A B^{\frac{1}{2}}$ related to that of $A$? Is there a general characterization for this?

Comment: I guess this can be reduced to the generalized eigenproblem described at the end of this section. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem

Comment: The only thing that stays constant is the signature of the matrix: 
the number of positive eigenvalues of $B^{\frac{1}{2}} A B^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is equal to the number of positive eigenvalues of $A$, same for the negative and zero-eigenvalues.